# WebApi ActionName delete route not working

Tags: c#, webapi

my project contains several WebApi controllers and each of them provides usually three actions: get(guid), post(data) and delete(guid),
A default route is described in the `WebApiconfig` for this requirement. (name: `ControllerAndId`)

Now I have to implement a controller which has to handle different post actions. For this requirement I tried to map another route with `ActionNames`. (name: `ControllerAndActionAndId`)

Since I have mapped the `ControllerAndActionAndId` route it is not possible to call the delete route of the "normal" controller (example: `Contactscontroller`).
 All routes are working except the delete routes.

> StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found'

There is an example of an usually ApiController:

```
    public class ContactsController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<Contact> Get()
    {
        return GetContacts();
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Post(Contact contact)
    {            
        SaveContact(contact);

        return Request.CreateResponse<Guid>(_code, contact.Id);
    }

    public void Delete(Guid id)
    {
        DeleteContact(id);
    }
}
```

Controller with ActionName-Route:

```
    public class AttachmentsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public Attachment Get(Guid attachmentId)
    {
        return GetAttachment(attachmentId);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("save")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Save(AttachmentSaveData saveData)
    {
        SaveAttachment(saveData);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("remove")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Remove(AttachmentDeleteData deleteData)
    {
       DeleteAttachment(deleteData);            
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig:

```
            // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Controller with ID
        // To handle routes like `/api/VTRouting/route/1`
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ControllerAndActionAndId",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new
            {
                id = RouteParameter.Optional,
                action = RouteParameter.Optional
            }
        );

        // Controller with ID
        // To handle routes like `/api/VTRouting/1`
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ControllerAndId",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new
            {
                id = RouteParameter.Optional
            }
        );
```

ClientAction delete function:

```
        private void Delete(string uri, int id)
    {
        using (HttpClient _client = new HttpClient())
        {
            _client.BaseAddress = BaseAddress;
            string _url = string.Format("{0}/{1}", uri, id);
            var _response = _client.DeleteAsync(_url).Result;

            if (!_response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }
    }
```

I currently have no further idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: Try use `[HttpDelete]` instead of `[HttpPost]` for your "remove" action

Comment: DeleteAsync method sends DELETE request. But you have POST methods

Comment: The AttachmentController is working fine now.
But the DELETE action of the ContactController is not working anymore.

Comment: Add HttpDelete attribute to delete action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Web API, you need add HTTP verb to action.

For example, your code must be as below:

```
public class ContactsController : ApiController
{ 
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Contact> Get()
    {
        return GetContacts();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(Contact contact)
    {            
        SaveContact(contact);

        return Request.CreateResponse<Guid>(_code, contact.Id);
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    public void Delete(Guid id)
    {
        DeleteContact(id);
    }
}
```

**Pay attention to Delete action**.

1. If you use HttpDelete verb on action, you must send delete request from your client  `httpClient.DeleteAsync(...)`.
2. If you use HttpPost verb on action, you must send post request from your client  `httpClient.PostAsync(...)`.

AttachmentsController is similar to ContactsController.

Answer (score 0):

I was focused to much on actions and routes of the controller.
But the solution was easy to find at client side:

```
        private void Delete<T>(string uri, T value)
    {
        using (HttpClient _client = new HttpClient())
        {
            _client.BaseAddress = BaseAddress;
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            string _url = string.Format("{0}/{1}", uri, value);
            var _response = _client.DeleteAsync(_url).Result;
        }
    }
```

This solution requires only one route in WebApiConfig:

```
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ControllerAndId",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new
            {
                id = RouteParameter.Optional
            }
        );
```

Soo easy.. thanks a lot !